# Hibernate get period between two timestamps

Tags: hibernate, timestamp

I need the time gap between two timestamps.
I need it in minutes or even better as a float of hours.

```
SUM(pe.endDateTime - pe.startDateTime)
```

I was able to use this code with the postgresql driver, but with h2 it did't work.
I can't believe that this is not possible this must be a common used function. 
And I don't want to lose the database independence by using a native query.

Thx for your help.